# SVG CSS keyframe animation help: Fade between 3 screens infinitely

Tags: svg, css-animations

I'd like to do a simple CSS keyframe animation in an SVG, an infinitely repeating 15-second slideshow-like presentation of three screens (let's call them #red, #yellow, #blue), each displaying for 5 seconds with roughly a 1-second fade between each. I can't quite figure out the technique/timing for this using keyframes and opacity, and I'm not finding anything this simple in reference websites or blog posts. Thank you for any and all help!

---

Figured it out:

```
  #red{
  animation: red-animate 20s ease infinite;
  }
  #yellow{
  animation: yellow-animate 20s ease infinite;
  }
  #blue{
  animation: blue-animate 20s ease infinite;
  }
  @keyframes red-animate {
  0%    {opacity: 1;}
  28%   {opacity: 1;}
  33%   {opacity: 0;}
  94%   {opacity: 0;}
  100%  {opacity: 1;}
  }
  @keyframes yellow-animate {
  0%    {opacity: 0;}
  28%   {opacity: 0;}
  33%   {opacity: 1;}
  61%   {opacity: 1;} 
  66%   {opacity: 0;} 
  100%  {opacity: 0}
  }
  @keyframes blue-animate {
  0%    {opacity: 0;}
  61%   {opacity: 0;}
  66%   {opacity: 1;}
  94%   {opacity: 1;}
  100%  {opacity: 0}
  }
```

Comment: Why not try SMIL. You might find it's easier to chain animations.

Comment: http://www.joningram.co.uk/article/svg-smil-frame-animation/ is a simple starter for SMIL

Answer (score 2):

I would keep it simple, and do everything inside a single keyframe animation.
If I am using a framework like Angular, with a stateful animation, I could have three animations in sequence, however, in pure CSS I would use just one (especially to animate a single SVG since it's what you need).

A simple example, without opacity in between those steps and animating `fill` color (made it 5 seconds long instead of 60 seconds to avoid wasting people's time):

```css
.rect {
fill: red;
animation: animate-color-and-opacity 5s ease infinite;
}  
  
  @keyframes animate-color-and-opacity {
  0%    {fill: red;}
  33%   {fill: blue;}
  66%   {fill: green;}
  }
```

```html
<svg width="400" height="110">
  <rect class="rect" width="300" height="100" />
</svg>
```

If you need the fade effect in between (15 seconds long animation, this time):

```css
.rect {
fill: red;
animation: animate-color-and-opacity 15s ease infinite;
}  
  
  @keyframes animate-color-and-opacity {
  0%    {fill: red; opacity: 1}
  
  19%   {opacity: 1}
  29%   {opacity: 0}
  33%   {fill: blue; opacity: 1}
  
  
  52%   {opacity: 1}
  62%   {opacity: 0}
  66%   {fill: green; opacity: 1}
  
  86%   {opacity: 1}
  96%   {opacity: 0}
  }
```

```html
<svg width="400" height="110">
  <rect class="rect" width="300" height="100" />
</svg>
```

If you don't want the fill transition in between, you could use `step-end`:

```css
.rect {
fill: red;
animation: animate-color-and-opacity 10s infinite step-end;
// or animation-timing-function: step-end; 
}  
  
  @keyframes animate-color-and-opacity {
  0%    {fill: red; opacity: 1}
  
  19%   {opacity: 1}
  29%   {opacity: 0}
  33%   {fill: blue; opacity: 1}
  
  
  52%   {opacity: 1}
  62%   {opacity: 0}
  66%   {fill: green; opacity: 1}
  
  86%   {opacity: 1}
  96%   {opacity: 0}
  }
```

```html
<svg width="400" height="110">
  <rect class="rect" width="300" height="100" />
</svg>
```